# Equivalent of `shopt -s autocd` in eshell

Tags: eshell

I use `shopt -s autocd` in the bash shell. It allows me to just type in the directory name and cd there. Is there some equivalent in eshell?

Answer (score 7):

I hate to break this to you, but it's the built-in default behavior. :)

```
Welcome to the Emacs shell

~/.emacs.d $ /
/ $
```

Comment: Joined just to upvote :)